# Serial Read with ORSSerialPort / Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, serial-port, orsserialport

I am trying to read a serial port in an XCode Cocoa app using the ORSSerialPort Library.  I got everything working where I can open a serial port and start reading data, but there is a glitch with the format when reading data:

When I run the demo code, it works just fine and the readings look like this (X,Y values):

> 1,0 
> 2,999 
> 3,1999 
> 4,3000 
> 5,4000 
> 6,5001

However, when running my app, the readings appear like this (using NSLog):

> 2013-08-06 19:53:59.649 TestApp[87361:303] Data: 1,0
>  2013-08-06
>   19:54:00.649 TestApp[87361:303] Data: 2,999
>  2013-08-06
>   19:54:00.653 TestApp[87361:303] Data: 
>  2013-08-06 19:54:01.652
>   TestApp[87361:303] Data: 3,1999
>  2013-08-06 19:54:02.651
>   TestApp[87361:303] Data: 4,3000
>  2013-08-06 19:54:03.651
>   TestApp[87361:303] Data: 5,400
>  2013-08-06 19:54:03.655
>   TestApp[87361:303] Data: 0
>  2013-08-06 19:54:04.654
>   TestApp[87361:303] Data: 6,5001

Notice that the 3rd log is blank, the 6th log is incomplete, and the 7th log should be the end of the 6th log.  It appears as if random return characters are sent, but I don't know what is causing it.  I haven't noticed a pattern yet in how/when the formatting goes bad.

Comment: What device are you reading data from?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm using an arduino to send serial data continuously with 1 sec interval.

Answer (score 0):

The serial port and associated APIs (including ORSSerialPort) don't know anything about the format of your data, so there's no guarantee that they'll deliver it in the same chunks as you expect. So, the fact that you get the last character of the "6th log" in a separate callback is not abnormal. To handle that, you need to buffer incoming data, and process it in a way that makes sense. You can't assume that you'll get a complete packet of data in every callback. The format you're using now isn't particularly suitable for that because it's impossible to reliably tell where one reading starts and the next begins. You can fix that a number of ways. The easiest is to make them a fixed length (e.g. pad with zeros). Even better would be to add some kind of start code, and/or end code that won't otherwise appear in the packet's contents.

As for the blank log statement on line 3, I'm not sure what to make of that. It seems like you're converting the data back to a string, and logging that? Presumably there's an invisible character there. What output do you get if you change that log statement to `NSLog(@"Data: %@", receivedData);` where `receivedData` is the NSData object passed to the `-serialPort:didReceiveData:` call instead of a string?

Comment: Data output of the NSData object without converting to a string shows the same behavior.   Thanks for the formatting suggestions, I will try it out.  But its still strange that it works flawlessly in your demo code, which makes me think I am missing something in the code.

Comment: I'm curious to know the actual value of the data received on the third log line.

It does seem strange that you get different results with my demo code and your own code. Without seeing more of your project, it's impossible to say what might be going on. Feel free to email me if you want to talk more.